# Regex: Get value between two strings in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

#### How do I extract a certain value between two substrings in redshift with regex?

I have strings like the one below in a column in redshift:

```
[{'code': 'bla', 'amount': '149.30', 'type': 'fixed_amount'}]
```

I want to extract the float number.
I used several regex expressions, but seems like redshift is not accepting them.

```
select order_id, discount_codes, regexp_substring(discount_codes, '''amount'': ''[^'']*') as value from orders_shopify_de
```

Gave me this error:

```
ERROR: function regexp_substring(character varying, "unknown") does not exist Hint
```

Also for example:

```
regexp_replace(discount_codes, '(?<=''amount'': '')(.*)(?='',)')
```

Gave me this error:

```
ERROR: function regexp_substring(character varying, "unknown") does not exist Hint
```

Is there a way to extract the float?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(discount_codes, '''amount'': ''([^'']*)', 1, 1, 'e')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew God bless you man :D this works! I will try to understand it and adapt it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(discount_codes, '''amount'': ''([^'']*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

The pattern is `'amount': '([^']*)` that matches

- `'amount': '` - a `'amount': '` string
- `([^']*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `'` chars.

The additional arguments in [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) are:

- `1` - start searching from the first char in the string
- `1` - tells the regex engine to extract the first occurrence of the pattern
- `'e'` - enables extraction of the subexpression (aka *capturing group* value) from the resulting match.